# Display date of a file in another column along with file name in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, substring

At the pageload()...

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
    List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = files;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Files are stored in "Uploads" folder. File name format is "date_filename" e.g "01-12-2014_filename". Can any one help me how to display the date in the first column and filename on the second column of gridview.

Further code...The Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText = "No files  available at the moment...">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text = "Download" CommandArgument = '<%#   Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

The download part...

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    Response.End();
```

}

I created a substring of the filename by just extracting only the date...but in no vain, i can display it on the gridview control.

Comment: You can try list of object and then bind that to grid and `object` will have property as `date`, `filename`.

Comment: @ArindamNayak Do i need to add a templatefield in the grid?

Comment: You are going in correct direction, you need to change `List<ListItem>` to `List<XYZ>` , where `XYZ` is a class and have required properties, give me some time, i will post answer for this.

Comment: Posted my answer, that might be helpful for you.

Comment: @shaiToro can you tried i posted anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a class that has required properties such as.

```
public class Thing
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then, create a List , and fill that will required values.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
List<Thing> lst = new List<Thing>();
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
 string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath); // you might add NULL check and _ check, if that has 2 elements after split.
 lst.Add(new Thing() { FileDate = filename.Split('_')[0], FileName = filename.Split('_')[1], FilePath = filePath });
}
GridView1.DataSource = lst;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

You are done with server side code change and now change aspx side with following, so that it will have required `property` name in `databind`.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="File Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FileDate" HeaderText="File Date" />
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" CommandArgument='<%#   Eval("FilePath") %>' runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile" ></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks...but what i need to display is the date which was part of the filename, not the creation date of the file... e.g(say) 03-05-2014_somefilename.txt, i need the 03-05-2014 to be displayed on the  gridview

Comment: @shaiToro , remove `FileDate` from `asp:BoundField` and append required date to `FileName` in `lst.Add(new Thing() { ....` .

Comment: i have multiple files in "Uploads" folder with that format

Comment: @shaiToro, i havn't checked your updated code, now i have change my answer, please use that

Answer (score 0):

Just Use This:

```
 Text = '<%#Eval("Value").ToString().Substring(0, 10)%>'
```

and Use in `GridView`

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="ownload"   
Text = '<%#Eval("Value").ToString().Substring(0, 10)%>'
runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now ... DataBinding: '_Default+Thing' does not contain a property with the name 'Value'.

Comment: asp.net Version 2.0,4.0...??

Comment: @shaiToro now updated i hope it will work definitely